# Hide apps from "More from developer"?

Tags: android, google-play

So I've created a Developer Account for the **Google Play Store** and have uploaded a few apps which are completely unrelated.

My concern is that in the `More from developer` section, all of my uploaded apps appear (as it would be expected). However, since these Apps aren't related in any way, different genre/topic/brand/company, is there a way to hide them? or avoid having the `More from developer` section?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Maybe a new account for a llc or something like that.  Your out $25 bucks.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid that.... for the time being.

Comment: "More from developer" does not mean "More of the same ilk from developer."  If you wrote a good app that somebody loves, they might just want to see what else you've come up with, based on faith in your ability - not necessarily a desire to see the same kind of app they've already seen.  This is a great way to broaden the audience for your apps; there's no need to run away from it.

Comment: Thanks @Carl, I do realize this. I'm not trying to discuss the purpose of said section - as I completely agree with you. I have my reasons in wanting to not show the relationship between the apps. Buy I guess that's why you would have to open extra developer accounts. It's just a shame, because for the time being I would prefer to avoid those $25...

Comment: Any solution for this "problem"?